# How can I tell gcc to warn me of strings being assigned an integer value?

Tags: c++, string, stl

This is my test case (note the WTF comment):

```
TEST(string_assignment)
{
std::string str;
std::string cheese="Cheese";
str=cheese;
CHECK_EQUAL(cheese, str);

long lval=0;
str=lval; //WTF - why does the compiler allow this ?

str="";
str.append(cheese);
CHECK_EQUAL(cheese, str);
}
```

I want to catch instances of std::string being assigned something other than another string or a char*. I had assumed that the compiler would reject the incompatible type but it is allowing it.

How can I tell gcc (version 4.4.3) to reject this silliness ? ... or is there some other way to force rejection of these incompatible types being assigned to std::string ?

Comment: @0A0D: Makes no difference here.

Comment: Sorry man, but what about **not assigning an integer to a string**? That's really not the most evil thing you can do and not prevent to be done in C++.

Comment: @Christian Rau - I added this to the test case because I changed the type of a variable in my main project and was very surprised when the code compiled (yes, guilty of using the compiler to bookmark variable usage)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that the following overload exists:

```
string &operator=(char)
```

The compiler can satisfy your assignment with a single implicit conversion, so it compiles.

I think the `-Wconversion` GCC flag is supposed to deal with this, but it doesn't seem to work, at least in GCC 4.1.2.

Comment: +1 but if you can answer the question about detecting it I'd be curious too.

Comment: Actually, I think you could implement the class so that it was a compile time error.  Just provide a templated `operator=` that won't compile.  But that wouldn't be standard conform; a legal program could do something like `long x = 'x'; someString = x;`.

Comment: With -Wconversion, I get "warning: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value". I'm going to try this and fix any other issues it reports with explicit casting.

Comment: Can I override the overload by implementing my own string &operator=(char) ?

Comment: @user1016736 No, since it has to be a member function and this would require you to alter your implementation's `std::string`.

Answer (score 3):

Because it can't.  Ultimately, because of C compatibility: a `long`, like all other built-in numeric types, converts implicitly to a `char`.  So in order to ban this, you'd also have to forbid `someString = someChar`.  Which wouldn't bother me too much, but for whatever reasons, the committee felt was necessary.

Answer (score 3):

It compiles because of the following overload:

```
string& operator=(char)
```

Use `g++ -Wconversion` in order to print warning messages.

And `g++ -Wconversion -Werror` to treat warning as error.

Comment: +1 because you actually answered the question:-).  Not just why it was not complaining, but how to get a complaint.  (This will also generate other complaints, but most of them will be justified as well.)

Comment: Nice - the addition o -Wconversion and -Werror forces me to check some other assignments, too !

Comment: @user1016736: I consider it a good habit to enable all warning flags. I almost always use `-Wall`, but unfortunately, it doesn't include `-Wconversion`, so one needs to include it manually.

Comment: I already have -Wall everywhere - I am now adding -Wconversion everywhere, too. Thank-you.