# How do I ensure type-safe string initialization?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, std

How do I make it so this code doesn't compile?

```cpp
std::string foo;
foo = 3;
```

I understand that `int` is convertible to `char` (a bug IMHO. thanks, C), and that `std::string` has a `char` assignment operator (also a bug IMHO).

Comment: Huh, not even an intellisense warning in Visual Studio 2019 for ne,  let alone a build warning.  Is it treated as a char?

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone/string-integer-assignment.html (See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7918198)

Comment: There is no legal way to stop this from compiling as `3` can be implicitly converted to any character type.

Comment: @Artyer thanks! is there an equivalent for gcc, do you know?

Comment: I wonder if there's a Microsoft equivalent to `g++ -Wconversion` ?  I don't see it in the link above

Comment: @DaveS Regarding your first comment, Yes.  As long as the value is known at compile time and it is in the bounds of the destination type then the implicit conversion is allowed to happen.

Comment: A roundabout way: `template<class CharT, class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>, class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>> class basic_crippled_string : public std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator> {
public: using std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>::basic_string; /* proxy implement the operator= overloads you want */
};`

Comment: If you take Ted's advice, you could implement `basic_crippled_string& operator=(std::same_as<char> auto)` instead of `basic_crippled_string& operator=(char)`.

Comment: Fwiw: I've seen that `operator=` used so rarely that I'd prefer if they deprecated it or at least make it like @DrewDormann suggested.

Comment: Ted's approach, while useful, doesn't actually address the OP's issue, since it would require the OP to change their code from `std::string foo;` to `basic_crippled_string foo;`, which would also stop working if `foo` is ever assigned to a `std::string&`/`std::string*` variable/parameter and then `operator=` invoked on that variable/parameter, since `operator=` is not `virtual`.  The OP asked how to make the shown code fail without changing it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree. It would be a very roundabout way to get a type-safer string and it would need to be used throughout the project etc. I wonder how many rules one would break if one simply changed it to Drews suggestion directly in the library implementation? :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo makes me wonder how much would actually break if *all* implicit conversions were deprecated in general. One can always use `static_cast` to do an explicit conversion when needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau All occurrences of `type* name = NULL;` would break.

Comment: @NathanOliver The standard has special wording to allow exactly that conversion, ie to allow a numeric literal of `0` (what `NULL` maps to) to be assigned to any pointer type. Just as `nullptr` can be assigned to any pointer type. So, that is not really an *implicit* conversion under that scenario, or at least it could be an aceptable one.

Comment: `g++ -Wconversion` doesn't catch this. at least not in c++20.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe could make your own `using string = std::basic_string<crippled_char>;` and have a `struct crippled_char` that allows a `char` but not an `int`.

Comment: Another way is wrap the string (or any type) and using type_traits to limit ctors/assigment operators like this simple example: https://godbolt.org/z/PPrMWb7K4
Or using this library if you want more complete and better implementation: https://github.com/foonathan/type_safe

Comment: @Elijay - While I suspect that addresses the question as asked, there would be a few gotchas in using it.   Firstly, that `string` would be distinct from `std::string` (since redefining types in `std` is not allowed).   Second (more important) programmers maintaining code will need to be aware that `std::string` and `string` are distinct types.   That  isn't exactly a natural assumption, so would be a source of subtle (and maybe not so subtle) gotchas when maintaining code (e.g. a developer adds code that assumes it is working with `std::string`, when it isn't).